# What is the correct use of 'quantity' in physics?

Tags: terminology, definition

How do we talk about [quantities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_quantity) in physics, is a quantity something common between objects in a system? Like Mass, is it a particular property of a particular object, 'the mass of particle A' or is is a each value of associated with a property of the system at a different time, a different quantity, e.g. 5kg is a quantity and 6kg is a quantity and at t=1 to t=2 there are two different 'quantities'.

Comment: Have you read [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_quantity)?

Answer (score 3):

You can pretty much go by the dictionary definition, or go with the recursive view that 'quantity' can be used to describe anything that can be 'quantified.' (humor)

That's it: if it can be measured, it can be a quantity.  Nothing needs to change or be compared.

Comment: Nice short explanation. In addition, physics quantity can be **measured** or **calculated**. Not necessary all physical quantities are measurable, but _derived_ quantities can be measurable. For example, take a look at [wave function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function) $\Psi$ which is a complex number of probability amplitude with no direct physical meaning. However, $| \Psi |^2$ is real-valued probability density which -this time- can be measured.

Comment: Also note that the English dictionaries include multiple meanings of *quantity* and also include the meaning as a *number* of something (discrete counting).

Comment: I have just one question, how do we talk about quantities being *different*, is the distance between A and B and the distance between C and B different quantities even if they both are the same values? do SI have a working definition of the notion?